# SQL script runs fine in local sqldeveloper but fails in IST environment when ran through SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a SQL script having many insert/update operations, when I run it locally through sqldeveloper it runs fine.
But when I promote the same script to other env (UNIX based), it fails there.
Reason: there is a column "Logic" VARCHAR(1000) of a table, that can have :  special charaters/new line characters / colon/commas.

My Question :  How can I make my local SQLDEVELOPER to behave similar to other env ? So that I can resolve the errors locally.

Comment: Could you please share the sample script and what error you are getting.

Comment: If you deploy with SQL*Plus, test with SQL*Plus (and preferably the same version as SQL*Plus you use for deployment, with the same character set and NLS settings)

Comment: update test set logic='when x will be devided by why, two possible results. (1) result. (2) null pointer. "If result is null pointer :- handle it"'

Comment: @GaryMyers.. will I require to install oracle client? Because currently when i run SQLPLUS on local, it says command not found. I think SQLDEVELOPER does not require a seperate oracle installation, that is the reason I am able to run in SQLDEVELOPER.

Comment: The instantclient sqlplus should be sufficient. It's just an unzip, not a full install

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full problematic statement, and enough information to make it a [mcve]. You said 'it fails' but didn't explain what that means - does it get an error? Or does it update zero rows - in which case does the table contain data in the IST environment? Or does it sit waiting for further input because you didn't end it with a semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that sqlplus <> SQL Developer.

Both have scripting engines with support of similar commands, but there are significant differences.

SQL Developer is a java program. The JDBC uses the OS env to determine your NLS session parameters where sqlplus uses env variables - so it's easy to have 1 SQL statement ran on the same machine have two different resultsets between the two programs.

Can you use sqldev to build your sqlplus scripts?

Yes. But it requires you to be cognizant of these differences, write code that's robust (don't assume things like nls_date_formats) AND that you test your scripts in sqlplus before pushing them to prod.

Or use SQLcl instead of sqlplus to promote your scripts - same code/engine as SQLDev.